# I've added a view within a UITableView and there is a gap between the view and the first cell. How can I remove it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uiview

I've added a view to a tableView and there is a gap between the view which is 44px high and the first cell.

Here's a screen shot from IB:

[image]

I've tried a few things such as changing the heightForHeaderInSection's value and also disabled adjust scroll view insets. None of these work properly. The view seems to be within the tableView and scrolls with it.

This is how things are looking in simulator:

[image]

Would appreciate some help here as I don't understand what exactly is causing this gap.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A great way to debug these types of problems is to set a background color. You could set the cells to red and the view to green. It would then be interesting to see if the red and green edges are flush with no white in between.

Based on your screenshot, it looks like nothing is wrong. And by that I mean it looks about right for a view height of 44 points and a cell immediately beneath it with no separator line above it (so it's hard to tell where one ends and the other begins).

Comment: Lol, you were right. I actually thought this originally but the space I thought was there looked big enough to allow room for that first separator. Could have saved myself a lot of time. Thanks for your debug methods also.